# Create macros for keyboard on Mac

Tags: macos, macros, keyboard

I want to create a combination of buttons to insert text in all the input box that i want in Mac.

For example:

> command + option + 0 
>   
> > Output : &bull ;

Possibly without using third-part software

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyboard combination, but if you look in `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Text`, you can enter a shortcut which will be automatically expanded in any text input widget, e.g. 'omw' -> 'On my way!'

Answer (score 0):

I started to feel the creep of work-related musculoskeletal disorder(WRMSD)/RSI today after getting back into development after a long time off. I'm using emacs and a terminal on a mac, and I just saved myself thousands of keystrokes so far today with "BetterTouchTool" at "https://folivora.ai".
this macro is only active if emacs has the cursor, saves my buffer, command+tab's over to the last active window(terminal), presses "up" to get the last command, hits enter, and then command+tab's back to emacs. Amazing. F13 is "print screen".

[image: screenshot]